# Difference in Behavior Between Firefox and Chrome for HTML Canvas fillRect operation and fontBoundingBoxAscent

Tags: firefox, html5-canvas

I am working on a bug in a library for Leaflet and I cannot figure out how to work around a difference in how Firefox and Chrome implement HTML Canvas.  It revolves around the ctx.fillRect function -- it does not appear to be working in Firefox.  On Chrome, the application works properly and the labels are properly coloured:

Chrome
[image]

However with Firefox it appears as such:

Firefox
[image]

The code in my library which draws the labels is:

```
  drawLabel(labelText, textColor, backgroundColor, labelPosition) {
    const textWidth = this.ctx.measureText(labelText).width;
    const textHeight = this.ctx.measureText(labelText).fontBoundingBoxAscent;

    // Calculate label xy position
    const labelX = labelPosition.x;
    const labelY = labelPosition.y;
    this.ctx.fillStyle = backgroundColor;
    // Magic numbers will centre the rectangle over the text
    this.ctx.fillRect(labelX - textWidth / 2 - 1, labelY - textHeight + 1, textWidth + 3, textHeight + 2);
    this.ctx.fillStyle = textColor;
    this.ctx.fillText(labelText, labelX - textWidth / 2, labelY);
  }
```

I've tried to leverage ctx.rect and ctx.fill as a substitute but that does not work.  Logging the ctx object did show that Chrome and Firefox implement Canvas context a little differently, but the fields that I am modifying do not appear to be different.

Comment: I suspect you have a problem with `fontBoundingBoxAscent`, which is not enabled in Firefox by default and requires an `about:config` change (`dom.textMetrics.fontBoundingBox.enabled`)

Comment: @sideshowbarker instead of a [fontBoundingBoxAscent], if you find "many" related questions, please create a more general tag name like [textmetrics]. We probably don't want one tag per property.

Comment: @Kaiido OK, fair enough. The problem I've been running into with some monitoring mechanisms I've been working on is that the SO search tool doesn't allow combining multiple keywords/phrases with logical OR ー whereas it does allow combining multiple _tags_ with logical OR.

Comment: So I'm hoping to find the sweet spot for working around the limitations in the SO search tool without creating an excessive amount of new tags, while also making the tag names as discoverable as possible for people asking questions. Any suggestions or guidance you have would be much appreciated.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Fixing the search tool would be the obvious one, but I feel your pain. I'm just pretty sure that adding one tag per interface property isn't "a good thing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `fontBoundingBoxAscent` is not enabled in Firefox by default and requires the user to turn it on in `about:config` under `dom.textMetrics.fontBoundingBox.enabled`.

Comment: And even then beware that the results will be inconsistent: https://github.com/web-platform-tests/interop/issues/159